# Move and Rename file on ftp site with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, sftp

I am using the net-sftp gem to download a file to memory:

```
sftp = Net::SFTP.start('ftp.myapp.com','user_name', :password => 'password')

records = sftp.download!("luigi/List.csv")
```

I then need to move my file, located remote at `luigi/List.csv` and rename it.

I want to move it here:

`"luigi/archive/List_#{Time.now}.csv"`

I would then like to delete the original file, located at `luigi/List.csv`.

How can I use ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0 to move, rename, and delete a file on my FTP site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `rename`:

```
sftp.rename("luigi/List.csv", "luigi/archive/List_#{Time.now}.csv")
```

assuming `luigi/archive` exists.

To just delete, there is the `remove` function. See the [Net::SFTP FAQ](http://net-ssh.github.io/sftp/v1/faq.html#2202502).