# Rails 4, Paperclip, Upload in FTP. How to rename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ftp, paperclip, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 4 and Paperclip.

Beacuse I need to upload files on FTP server i'm using this great gem:

https://github.com/xing/paperclip-storage-ftp

Everything works perfect in local, but in FTP I can't rename files using this code:

```
  def rename_myfile
    if self.rename.present?
      path = self.myfile.path
      FileUtils.move(myfile.path, File.join(File.dirname(myfile.path), self.rename))
      self.myfile_file_name = self.rename
    end
  end
```

I got an error:

No such file or directory @ sys_fail2 - (/myfiles/19/original/myfileOriginalName.jpg, /myfiles/19/original/myfileRenamedName.jpg)

How to enter in ftp with FileUtils.move???

Create and Delete are working very well!

https://github.com/xing/paperclip-storage-ftp/issues/28

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the full path to the file not just the file's dirname and name. change your `FileUtils.move` line to this:

```
orig_full_path = Rails.root.join "public", myfile.path # assuming they're saved in your public directory
new_full_path = Rails.root.join "public", File.dirname(myfile.path), self.rename
FileUtils.move orig_full_path, new_full_path
```

The idea here is to get the absolute path to your files. Before you were just giving FileUtils this path: `/myfiles/19/original/myfileOriginalName.jpg` which means it will look for the file in a folder `/myfiles` in the root of your file system. But they're actually in your Rails folder. So you should use `Rails.root.join` to get the true absolute path: `/Users/me/my_rails_project/public/myfiles/19/original/myfileOriginalName.jpg`.

Comment: Also in ftp it works? Thanks a lot for your help, Diego!

Comment: I read through the `paperclip-storage-ftp` code briefly and they don't seem to provide a method to rename files on the remote FTP server. You'd have to download the file rename it and then upload it again. Or you could use another gem to do the rename: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260911/move-and-rename-file-on-ftp-site-with-ruby

Comment: Diego, thanks again. I'm trying to create a method to rename the file in paperclip-storage-ftp and then fork it. I'm using this code, but i got an error. Where I'm wrong? `def rename(newfilename)
        with_primary_ftp_server do |server|
          server.rename(file, newfilename)
        end
      end` And how to use Net::SFTP together with paperclip-storage-ftp?